# What is the recommended or most precise way, to call a function after a specific time?

Tags: c++, timing

I wrote a little program to launch and record a stereo setup of cameras. I would like to record a sequence of 100ms. The thing is: I don't know how to time the functions with the highest possible precision. I found the header `<unistd.h>` which includes the function `usleep` which can pause the execution for a specified microsecond interval. So in my program I'm doing something like this:

```
left_camera.start_recording();
right_camera.start_recording();
usleep(100000);
left_camera.stop_recording();
right_camera.stop_recording();
```

Is there a better way to ensure precise timing between the two functions?

Comment: There is no single recommended way.   Depending on what version of unix you have (linux versus BSD versus .... , kernel version, etc) there are different ways of achieving the effect.   The choice may also be affected by hardware capability (e.g. if there is a high precision hardware timer or not).   You'll need to read the documentation for your particular system.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't ensure anything except that you sleep for no less than 100 ms. From `man usleep`: "System activity may lengthen the sleep by an indeterminate amount." Abandon the idea of "highest possible precision" and decide what precision you actually need. Then you can start searching for a solution.

Comment: there are ways to get nanoseconds or even picoseconds accuracy, but not without investing a major amount of effort (and dedicated hardware). "highest possible precision" is too imprecise. What precision do you really need?

Comment: Do you need the sleep, or do you need a 100ms delay? Is busy-waiting an option?

Comment: @divinas I just need the delay. I want the cameras to be recording for 100ms. What does "busy-waiting" mean? Might be an option.

Comment: @molbdnilo In that case I'll probably rather write a post processing script to just cut away everything, that was recorded after the 100ms. I just hoped, there was a way of delaying with a higher precision. But I kind of assumed, it wouldn't be that easy.

Comment: Busy-wait basically means a loop that does nothing until enough time passes. You can use a high-precision timer to get the current timestamp, and do a loop until the timestamp exceeds your duration. You are still not guaranteed to run exactly 100ms, because the OS will schedule your process, but you'll most probably get pretty close to that. You can most probably play with setting the a higher thread priority to get less switches. This can most probably give you some more precision.
p.s This wastes a lot of CPU cycles -> heat, power consumption, CPU availability for others will suffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use std::this_thread::sleep_for (C++11)

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(500));
}
```

Comment: `sleep_for` sleeps for *at least* the specified time span. There is no formal upper limit.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'd be surprised if you could get a formal upper limit out of anything running under the control of an OS scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

sleep is not better way to implement a timer. You can use asio asynchronous timer feature from c++ boost library. you can create the timer and this shall call register function after timer expires

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

void func(const boost::system::error_code&)
{
    std::cout << "in func" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(0.1));
  t.async_wait(&func);
  io.run();
  return 0;
}
```

Link libboost_system library while compiling
For more information refer:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html